# SELECT INTO OUTFILE giving OS errno 13

Tags: mysql

We recently migrated from `MySQL5.6.51` to `MySQL8.0.28` (`Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`) and we have started noticing some differences.  One of the problems has been recreated using a sample database, with a table called `people`.

```
mysql> show tables;
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_Sandbox |
+-------------------+
| people            |
+-------------------+
```

We can SELECT INTO OUTFILE to `/tmp` directory without any issues.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM people INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/people.txt';
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

However, we are getting are getting an error with another directory (let us call it `/mysql_tmp`), even though it has 777 permissions and user and group are `mysql`

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM people INTO OUTFILE '/mysql_tmp/people.txt';
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/mysql_tmp/people.txt' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
```

Here is the truncated output of `ls -l`:

```
$ ls -l /
...
drwxrwxrwx   2 mysql       mysql           4096 Apr  5 13:52 mysql_tmp
...
drwxrwxrwt  26 root        root            4096 Apr  5 14:17 tmp
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you update from `old-version` to `new-version` it might be smart to check all the [release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/) between those versions.

[Google: mysql release notes outfile](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+release+notes+outfile) might help:

- Changes in MySQL 8.0.20 (2020-04-27, General Availability)

> Previously, the INTO clause for SELECT statements could appear at
> either of two positions:
>
> Before FROM:
>
> SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' FROM table_name; Before a trailing
> locking clause:
>
> SELECT * FROM table_name INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' FOR UPDATE; INTO now
> can appear in a third position, at the end of SELECT statements:
>
> SELECT * FROM table_name FOR UPDATE INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'; Placing
> INTO at the end is the preferred position. The position before a
> locking clause is now deprecated and support for it will be removed in
> a future MySQL version. In other words, INTO after FROM but not at the
> end of the SELECT produces a warning.
>
> Additionally, some changes have been made for UNION with respect to
> INTO. These UNION variants containing INTO are syntactically correct
> and produce the same result:
>
> ... UNION SELECT * FROM table_name INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'; ... UNION
> (SELECT * FROM table_name) INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'; ... UNION SELECT
>
> - INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' FROM table_name; ... UNION (SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' FROM table_name); However, the last two variants
>   are confusing, as if they collect information from the named table
>   rather than the entire query expression (the UNION). Those two UNION
>   variants containing INTO now are deprecated and support for them will
>   be removed in a future MySQL version. Thus:
>
> In the trailing query block of a query expression, use of INTO before
> FROM produces a warning.
>
> In a parenthesized trailing block of a query expression, use of INTO
> (regardless of its position relative to FROM) produces a warning.
>
> The deprecations apply to all INTO forms: INTO OUTFILE, INTO DUMPFILE,
> and INTO var_list.

- Changes in MySQL 8.0.17 (2019-07-22, General Availability)

> The umask for files created using SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE or SELECT
> ... INTO DUMPFILE was changed from 0666 to 0640. The LOAD_FILE()
> function no longer requires files to be world-readable, just readable
> by the server. (Bug #24513720)

- Changes in MySQL 8.0.4 (2018-01-23, Release Candidate)

> FILE privilege checking for prepared SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE
> statements was incorrect. (Bug #27094955)

I stopped checking here, because this change in 8.0.4 might be your problem.